# How to create a Notification Hub just for TESTING in Azure for both Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed a cross platform app using Xamarin. It receives push notifications via a web API hosted in Microsoft Azure. I currently also have a Notification Hub as a resource hosted in Azure.

The issue is that in order to add more features to the app, I have to also test that the app receives push notifications, but I do not want to send the push notifications from my app troubleshooting process to all the users who already downloaded  the app from the store (in production mode) and are using it.

How can I create a separate channel for testing? I am thinking to create another push notification hub with a separate  controller method in the web API
that would only send notifications in developer mode. But how exactly can that be achieved.

In iOS the notification  hub has a Production/Sandbox switch. I am thinking that by uploading a p12 made with Development certificates I could use send notifications only in development mode on a test device, but that is not the case for Android.

Also aren't notification hubs connected to the package name of the app, so then even in Development/Testing Mode all the users who downloaded the app would receive notifications from the testing in development?

Can I only send notifications in developer mode without changing the package name of the app, via an alternate push notification hub?

Comment: You can use the TestFlight in iOS

Comment: Agree with @Lucas Zhang - MSFT, you can refer to the [official site](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) for an easy invite to the users to test your app. Use [this guide](https://testflight.apple.com/) to test your app using "TestFlight". Be noted of the required platforms (iOS apps: iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch running iOS 8 or later. iMessage apps and sticker packs require iOS 10 or later, tvOS apps: Apple TV running tvOS 9 or later) and with an exception for the Mac apps.

Comment: Those were good suggestions but I thought of another option, which is to create another Post method in a separate controller that takes an installation id as a parameter and sends message body to specific "installation Id" which would be my development mobile device. And this is while using the same Notification hub used in Production. This way I can test without sending the notifications to everyone using app, what do you guys think of that option?